# How to print the current working directory in Unix shell in C++?

Tags: shell, c++11, unix, operating-system

I am using the `chdir()` method inside it, so I can't define `cwd` as a string.

How can I print the current working directory in Unix shell in C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getcwd function. Or, if you insist on using the shell, use the system function to execute pwd.